# how to set the value in hidden text box using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am trying to add text in this text box but not getting it on the other hand code works fine when the textbox is visible.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox></div>
```

Comment: do you just want a hidden input?

Comment: i want a hidden input which gets its value from jquery

Comment: just add `type="hidden"` and remove the visibility part

Comment: type="hidden" does not hide the textbox

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: please Correct me if i'm wrong ..you want an Textbox whose value can be field by jquery only not other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" ClientIDMode="Static" style="display:none;" runat="server" Visible="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

you can set text box value using jquery like this:

```
$('input#TextBox1').val("anyvalue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `visible=false` causes the control not to be rendered and therefore it wouldn't have a value posted back to the server.

Edits:
You might use a hidden input control to contain the data you want to post to the client, but not be visible in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Set the texbox to be invisible in jquery `$(document).ready` instead of  `Visible="False"`